# How to assign value to parent attribute and use it in inherited function?

Tags: python, oop

When trying to rewrite and instantiate a different object in child, I cannot access it through inherited parent function.

```
class kafka(object):
    __topic = ''
    __bootstrap_servers = ''
    __producer : Producer

    def __init__(self, *, topic: str, brokers: str, **kwargs):
        self.__bootstrap_servers = brokers
        self.__topic = topic

        conf = {
            'bootstrap.servers': self.__bootstrap_servers,
            'other configs': 'config values' #<--------------
            }
        self.__producer = Producer(conf)

    def save(self, m: message) -> bool:
        r = self.__producer.produce(self.__topic, m.get())
        self.__producer.flush()
        return r

class oldkafka(kafka):
    def __init__(self, *, topic: str, brokers: str, **kwargs):
        self.__bootstrap_servers = brokers
        self.__topic = topic
        conf = {
            'bootstrap.servers': self.__bootstrap_servers,
            }
        self.__producer = Producer(conf)
```

Error:

```
k = oldkafka(topic='topic',brokers='broker:9092')
k.save('message')

#r = self.__producer.produce(self.__topic, m.get())
#AttributeError: 'oldkafka' object has no attribute '_kafka__producer'
```

How do I assign values to class `self` attributes in the child class in order to use it in the inherited function?

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: See information in the documentation on the "[name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers)" of indentifiers. This means that to reference things in the parent class from the derived class you will need to use a prefix of `_kafka__.` instead of simply `__.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefixing attribute names with `__` makes them pseudo-private; they're name-mangled by the compiler to include the name of the class the function was defined in, as you can see in your error message, where using `self.__producer` in a method of `kafka` actually looked up the name-mangled attribute name, `_kafka__producer` (the `__producer` assigned in the child would be named `_oldkafka__producer`, and since you didn't invoke the parent's `__init__`, `_kafka__producer` was never created).

If you want the same variable with the same name to be accessible at other layers of the inheritance chain, don't use private variables; use a single underscore `_` to indicate it's not public, without invoking name-mangling. In this case, this just means changing (at least) `__producer` to `_producer` in both the parent and child classes (odds are you want to do the same for `__topic` and `__bootstrap_servers`, assuming they're supposed to be used by both parent and child classes).

Side-note: It's generally a bad idea to write initializers that don't invoke the initializer of their parent class. If you can find some way to make `oldkafka` reuse as much of `kafka`'s `__init__` as possible (either all of it, and don't implement `__init__` on the child, or if the child must do more, delegate to the parent with `super().__init__(... args to parent go here ...)`), that's going to be much better code. For example:

```
class kafka(object):
    __topic: str
    __bootstrap_servers: str
    __producer: Producer

    def __init__(self, *, topic: str, brokers: str, **kwargs):
        self.__bootstrap_servers = brokers
        self.__topic = topic
        self.__producer = self._make_producer(**kwargs)

    def _make_producer(self, **kwargs):
        conf = {
            'bootstrap.servers': self.__bootstrap_servers,
            'other configs': 'config values'
            }
        return Producer(conf)

    # rest of class

class oldkafka(kafka):
    # ... does not override __init__ at all
    def _make_producer(self, **kwargs):
        return Producer({'bootstrap.servers': self.__bootstrap_servers})

    # rest of class
```

Comment: fyi, that custom ```make_producer``` function i created right after your first unedited answer. thanks